# How to make temporarily center-aligned math equation, when using option [fleqn] for amsmath

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I am using `fleqn` for amsmath. So the euqation is default left-aligned.

Now I want to teamporarily make one equation center-aligned. How to do this?

Thank you all.
[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{left-align}
   \begin{equation}
        y = x 
   \end{equation}

\section{center-align}
    \begin{equation}
        \centering
         y = x + x
     \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `ceqn` environment, from `nccmath` is for. Conversely, it defines a `fleqn` environment for temporarily left-aligned groups of equations  in the default context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\section{left-align}
   \begin{equation}
        y = x
   \end{equation}

\section{center-align}

\begin{ceqn}
    \begin{equation}
        \centering
         y = x + x
     \end{equation}
\end{ceqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]